# Как удалить из массива объект по двум свойствам?

Tags: javascript, массивы

**Как удалить из массива объект по двум свойствам?**

```
 const arr = [
      {id: 51,
      itemId: 1},
       {id: 52,
      itemId: 1},
      {id: 51,
      itemId: 2},
       {id: 52,
      itemId: 2},
    ]
```

Нужно удалить с объект с id: 51 и itemId: 1

Результат должен быть такой:

```
const arr = [
   {id: 52,
  itemId: 1},
  {id: 51,
  itemId: 2},
   {id: 52,
  itemId: 2},
]
```

*Данные массива динамические, так что удалить первый или последний не получиться*

*я пытался с помощью filter, но видимо он работает не так как я думал :*

```
const res = arr.filter((obj)=> obj.id !== 52 && obj.itemId !== 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо изменить условие в filter, что бы возвращалось false при нахождении элемента с заданными условиями исключения.

В вашем случае, возвращается false если одно из значений не соовпало.

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 51,
    itemId: 1},
  {id: 52,
    itemId: 1},
  {id: 51,
    itemId: 2},
  {id: 52,
    itemId: 2},
]

console.log(arr.filter((obj)=> !(obj.id === 52 && obj.itemId === 1)));
console.log(arr.filter((obj)=> !(obj.id === 52 && obj.itemId === 2)));
console.log(arr.filter((obj)=> !(obj.id === 51 && obj.itemId === 1)));
console.log(arr.filter((obj)=> !(obj.id === 51 && obj.itemId === 2)));
```

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось не так сложно

Answer (score 0):

Наверное стОит найти индекс элемента по параметрам и удалить потом по индексу

```js
let arr = [
      {id: 51, itemId: 1},
      {id: 52, itemId: 1},
      {id: 51, itemId: 2},
      {id: 52, itemId: 2},
    ];

arr.splice(arr.findIndex((obj)=> obj.id == 51 && obj.itemId == 1), 1)
console.log(arr);
```